# Change ajax page url on multisite

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an ajax page on a multisite. The problem is at the moment when I have this code my second site pulls in the main sites urls with ajax

```
 jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/ajax',
    data: {
        postId: postid,
    },
```

I tried something like this code below and that helps me get the right site url but it also includes the current page. So for example something like this POST http://bla.bom.net/current-page/ajax

I need it to bring in the ajax page without any current page in the url
so for example  POST http://bla.bom.net/ajax

```
 jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: document.URL+'/ajax',
    data: {
         postId: postid,
    }
```

Comment: `/` makes it go to the root of the domain.  Change `/ajax` to `./ajax`

Comment: I think that '/ajax' suppose to work cause it is relative to the current domain.

Comment: Then `/ajax` should work.  That would go to `http://domain/ajax`

Comment: It works just fine on the main site but not on the second site.. The second site pulls in the ajax url for the main site

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: window.location.hostname +'/ajax',
    data: {
         postId: postid,
    });
```

Comment: Tried it it basically repeats the url so something like                  POST http://blaster.bla.net/listen-watch/blaster.bla.net/ajax and gives me a 4040 error